# The factor-solve method

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For what values of $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ is the $n\times n$ matrix nonsingular.

$A=\begin{bmatrix} 
a_1 & 1 & 0 &.&.&.& 0 & 0 \\
a_2 & 0 & 1 &.&.&.& 0 & 0 \\
. & . & . &.&.&.& . & . \\
. & . & . &.&.&.& . & . \\
. & . & . &.&.&.& . & . \\
a_{n-2} & 0 & 0 &.&.&.& 1 & 0 \\
a_{n-1} & 0 & 0 &.&.&.& 0 & 1 \\
a_{n} & 0 & 0 &.&.&.& 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: What do you think? **Hint**: Only one value matters, which one?

Comment: \begin{bmatrix} 
a_i & I \\
a_n & 0
\end{bmatrix}. I was thinking about this matrix and solving $AX=I$

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I'll be more careful @JMoravitz

Comment: Don't you see an easy way to compute the determinant ?

Comment: @angelo086 For a (quadratic) matrix to be nonsingular is the same as to say all (row- / or column) vectors are independent which is the same as to say that the matrix has full rank/the image has dimension n. What happens, if we put $a_n=0$? Is any of these violated? What happens if we put $a_n\neq 0$ and change the other $a_i$? Do we change one of the conditions above?

Comment: So, as long an $a_n\neq0$, we can say A is nonsingular

Comment: @angelo086 7.1 [here](https://www.coursehero.com/file/10554042/20085ee103-1-hw4-sols/)

Answer (score 1):

Pf 1:

$$\det(A) = (-1)^{n-1}a_{n} \det(I_{n \times 1}) = (-1)^{n-1}a_{n} \ne 0 \iff a_n \ne 0$$

QED

---

Pf 2:

If you move the first column all the way to the right, you would have an augmented matrix for the linear system

$$Bx=a \tag{*}$$

where

$$a = [a_1, \cdots, a_n]^T \in \mathbb R^{n, 1}$$

$$x = [x_1, \cdots, x_{n-1}]^T \in \mathbb R^{n \times 1,1}$$

and $B \in \mathbb R^{n, n \times 1}$ is $I_{n \times 1}$ with an extra row of zeroes below it ie $$[a | B] = A$$

Now observe that the last row of $(*)$ is:

$$0x_1 + 0x_2 + \cdots 0x_{n-1} = a_{n}$$

This is consistent iff $$a_n = 0$$

Now observe that

1. $$[\text{x satisfies} \ (*) \iff \ \text{x satisfies} \ (I_{n \times 1}x = [a_1, \cdots, a_{n-1}]^T]) \iff [a_n = 0]$$
2. $$[(*) \ \text{has a unique solution} \ \iff \ (I_{n \times 1}x = [a_1, \cdots, a_{n-1}]^T \ \text{has a unique solution})]\iff [a_n = 0]$$
3. $$[B \ \text{has full rank} \iff I_{n \times 1} \text{has full rank}] \iff [a_n = 0]$$
4. $$B \ \text{has full rank} \iff A \ \text{has full rank}$$

Thus

$$[A \ \text{has full rank} \iff I_{n \times 1} \text{has full rank}] \iff [a_n = 0]$$

$$\to [A \ \text{has full rank}] \iff [a_n = 0] \tag{1}$$

$$\to [\det(A) \ne 0] \iff [a_n = 0] \tag{2}$$

where

$(1)$ is true because $I_{n \times 1}$ is invertible and hence $\text{has full rank}$

$(2)$ is true because $A$ is square. Note that $det(B)$ is meaningless.

QED